# In BundleConfig.cs cannot find BundleCollection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add BundleConfig.cs to my Mvc project. Also i added to Global.asax

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

But there is an error with BundleTable. My BundleConfig.cs Code is:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give us more details about the error?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `System.Web.Optimization` [namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization(v=vs.110).aspx) to `BundleConfig.cs`.

Also you might need to install `Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework` [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/)

Comment: Thanks. Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization solved my problem.

Comment: Mine too. In my case, the problem started when my computer was refreshed and I re-installed Visual Studio. The above install-package command sorted out all the problems.